# L’uso del Lei in italiano

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Quando è stato usato per la prima volta il lei invece del voi nella lingua italiana? È stato importato da un’altra lingua, oppure ha avuto origine in Italia?

Answer (score 4):

L'uso del *lei* deriva, per semplificazione, dalle forme del tipo *vossignoria*, *vostra eccellenza*, etc. Questa forma è nativa all'italiano e risale al tredicesimo secolo, ma è stata favorita dall'analogia con lo spagnolo *usted*. La breve repressione in epoca fascista è servita solo a rendere il *lei* più popolare con la caduta del regime.

Purtroppo non ho modo di accedere al libro di Brunet (vedi sotto), e nessuna delle fonti che ho a disposizione dà esempi di quest'uso del *lei* nel Duecento.

---

Il breve paragrafo di cui sopra è un riassunto di *A Linguistic History of Italian*, di Martin Maiden (sezione 9.6 *Pronouns of address*), che riporto qui di seguito per completezza. La traduzione in italiano è mia.

> [The pronouns of address *lei* and *loro*] originate in the use as forms of address of honorific nouns, rather like English ‘your honour’, ‘your worship’, ‘your ladyship’ – cf. Brown and Levinson (1987: 276f.); the language of the sixteenth century developed a profusion of honorifics such as *vostra signoria*; *vossignoria*; *vostra eccellenza*, etc. It seems that the use of such devices received a considerable impetus from Spanish models, such as *Vuestra Merced* (> *usted*) in the sixteenth century, although the employment of third person forms is detectable as early as the thirteenth (cf. Brunet (1987: 12)). These (usually feminine) nouns are replaced by feminine third person pronouns, which are the source of modern *Ella*, *Lei* and plural *Loro*. [...] The perception that third person address forms are a product of foreign influence prompted the Fascist authorities, in the 1930s, to denounce Lei in favour of the supposedly more ‘Italian’ polite *voi* (see Brunet (1987: 69–78)). Such denunciation served only to promote a reaction in favour of *Lei* in the post-Fascist period.

> [I pronomi di indirizzo *lei* e loro*] hanno origine nelle forme di indirizzo di nomi onorifici, come *vostro onore*, *signoria vostra*, etc. [...]; il linguaggio del sedicesimo secolo sviluppò una profusione di onorifici come *vostra signoria*; *vossignoria*; *vostra eccellenza*, etc. Sembra che l'uso di tali forme ricevette un considerabile impeto da modelli spagnoli, come *Vuestra Merced* (> *usted*) nel sedicesimo secolo, sebbene l'impiego di forme della terza persona sia discernibile sin dal tredicesimo (cf. Brunet (1987: 12)). Questi nomi (solitamente femminili) sono rimpiazzati da pronomi femminili di terza persona, che solo la fonte dei moderni *Ella*, *Lei* e il plurale *Loro*. [...] La percezione che le fome di indirizzo di terza persona fossero un prodotto dell'influenza straniera spinse le autorità fasciste, negli anni trenta, a denunciare *Lei* in favore del *voi* di cortesia, presunto più 'Italiano'(vedi Brunet (1987: 69-78)). Una tale denuncia servì solo a promuovere una reazione in favore del *Lei* nel periodo post-fascista.

I riferimenti a Brunet sono da

> BRUNET, J. (1987) Grammaire critique de l'italien. 9. Tu, voi, Lei. Paris: Université de Paris VIII: Vincennes.