Is 'Voi' formal?
For my exam I need to write a formal letter and I'm wondering if 'voi' is appropriate. Sometimes I hear it is only for informal and sometimes I hear it is formal and informal. I'm trying to be pedantic as my exam is a bit old fashioned.

Italian used to have a system with three possible ways to address a single person: tu, Lei, and Voi. There are several past questions and answers about this, at least: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/difference-between-darsi-del-tu-and-del-lei; https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/13713/l-uso-del-lei-in-italiano; https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/who-decided-the-switch-from-voi-to-lei-in-the-20th-century

My father still remembers when he had to use voi when talking to his father.

It would help to know in which sentence you would use voi. For the second person plural, there is only voi, differently from the third person plural, for which you could use loro or essi.

‘Voi’ is considered a formal expression to refer to a group of people, sometimes it may be used also to refer to a single person (instead of ‘Lei’) but it is more common in the southern regions of Italy.

Actually, it's informal (though almost universally accepted) to use voi for several persons. The formal way to address more than one person is Loro.

@DaG To me using Loro for several people feels unbelievably stuffy, not formal, at the level of parody. Is it still used in your idiolect? Rome must be a weirder place than I thought :).

@DenisNardin, no, the last time I heard it in real life it must have been several years ago (even though I won't deny Rome to be a weird place). On the other hand, I still consider it formal high use (perhaps, say, in some administrative act) and Serianni's Italiano (VII.84) gives loro on the same level as voi among the “pronomi allocutivi reverenziali”.

@DenisNardin I do not find Loro sono qui. stuffy. I would rather use loro in that sentence, instead of essi. (It could be because I have always lived in Brescia.)

@DaG Isn't loro an alternative for essi? (I cannot find of an alternative word for voi, except voialtri.)

Once, voi was used to refer to a single person, instead of tu. My father still remembers when he had to use voi even when speaking to his father.

@apaderno: Both loro and essi are pronouns for the third plural person (with slight difference in usage), while as a formal way to address more than one person only loro is (or was) used.

@apaderno I wouldn't use either loro or essi. While talking to multiple people I would always use voi (likely without pronoun, as "siete qui"), even in formal speech. I've seen Loro used as a formal address only in letters from banks, and never essi in documents written after 1900. Funny because our regions of origin are not so far from each other (I'm from Venice)

@Denis To me, Voi siete qui. means that the sentence is said to one of those people that should be here. Siete arrivati? Sì, siamo arrivati da cinque minuti.

@DaG Right, but the question is about voi.

@apaderno I feel there is some misunderstanding. Do you mean that the sentence is addressed to only one of the persons (as opposed to the group)?

@apaderno: Yes, but I wasn't answering the question. I was pointing out that the answer under which we are commenting makes a wrong assertion («‘Voi’ is considered a formal expression to refer to a group of people»).

@DenisNardin No. Voi includes the person to whom I speak. Reading comments about loro in a question about voi is quite confusing. I guess they do not make things clearer to people who are learning Italian.

@DaG Well, voi is used for more than one person, if we exclude the case it is used like lei. Also loro is used for more than one person, but voi and essi/loro is not used to refer to the same group of people. I know you are not answering the question, but a comment like The formal way to address more than one person is Loro. probably just confuses people who are learning Italian.

@Paderno: I'm sorry if you found “The formal way to address more than one person is Loro” confusing, but as I repeat it was strictly in response to the above answer, that claimed that “‘Voi’ is considered a formal expression to refer to a group of people”, which is false. Thanks to our exchange, I believe this is now clarified for future readers.

Si! Its more formal ;)
But in Italy we are not using it that often... You know everybody is your family

Welcome to Italian.SE! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help].
